# monit fails to run the command to start goliath server

Tags: monit

can someone shed some clues as to why, when i run this command manually on terminal:

/bin/bash -c 'cd /home/david/live && bundle exec ruby /home/david/live/api/goliath.rb -sv -e prod'

its going to fire my server just fine - but when its on monitrc like so:

start program = "/bin/bash -c 'cd /home/david/live && bundle exec ruby /home/david/live/api/goliath.rb -sv -e prod'"

its just going to repeatedly fail to start / execute that command line

[UTC Sep 17 01:00:25] error    : 'goliath' process is not running
[UTC Sep 17 01:00:25] info     : 'goliath' trying to restart
[UTC Sep 17 01:00:25] info     : 'goliath' start: /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify UID and GID as monit runs as root.

```
check process myserver 
  with pidfile "/home/path/to/myserver.pid"
  start program = "/bin/bash -c 'cd /home/david/live && bundle exec ruby /home/david/live/api/goliath.rb -sv -e prod'"
    as uid myserver_uid and gid myserver_gid
```

To debug, you could try to output to a file and check this file to have more details.

```
check process myserver 
  with pidfile "/home/path/to/myserver.pid"
  start program = "/bin/bash -c 'cd /home/david/live && bundle exec ruby /home/david/live/api/goliath.rb -sv -e prod' >> /tmp/myserver.log 2>&1"
    as uid myserver_uid and gid myserver_gid
```